# Looping through a Laravel collection to check for same value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I will appreciate any help on solving this please. I am working on Laravel project. I have a collection like so;
`$products = Product::all();`
Each product in the collection has a column called status, which is either set to 0, 1 or 2. Now I want to loop through my collection, if ALL the products status value returns 0, I want to display something like "exhausted" at the frontend, else show something else. I have tried this but couldn't achieve just what I wanted;

```
   $status = 0;
   foreach($products as $product){
      if($product->status == 0{
          $status = 0;
          return "exhausted";
      }
      return "not exhausted";
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Collection::every()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-every):

```
if ($products->every(fn($product) => $product->status === 0)) {
    return "exhausted";
}
return "not exhausted";
```

Comment: Thanks for method `every()`, did not know it. Should be the correct answer because this is pure Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

What about that, if it's only when all Status are at 0:

```
   $status = "exhausted";
   foreach($products as $product){
      if($product->status != 0){
         $status = "not exhausted";
         break;
      }
   }
   return $status;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eloquent to get a Collection and then use the Collection's count method. Example:

```
$products = Product::all();
$count = $products->whereStatus(0)->get()->count();
return $count == 0 ? "Exhausted": "WhatEverYouwant";
```